# Entity Framework 6.1 setting CommitFailureHandler as the Transaction Handler is causing SQL Server Log In Failure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got a SQL Server mirroring set up with a primary, secondary and witness to provide automatic failover for my application. I've been experimenting with using the `CommitFailureHandler` class but I've run into a problem when using it in a specific scenario:

- In the connection string the database server that is currently the
  Mirror must specified as the Data Source and the Principal must be
  specified as the Failover Partner.
- The application must have migrations to perform against the database
- The __TransactionHistory table must not exist

If any of those three conditions are not present then it works without problems.

When this situation does occur then a `SqlException` is thrown saying that Login Failed for the given user. I also the following messages in the SQL Server event log (on the Mirror instance):

> - Login failed for user 'myUser'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'myDatabase'.
> - Login failed for user 'myUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.

For the record, the login and password are correct and work fine when any one of the three conditions are not true.

Here is the line where I set the transaction handler in my Database Configuration class:

```
SetTransactionHandler(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, () => new CommitFailureHandler());
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this issue on the entity framework issues tracker: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2050

It appears that there is a bug in EF 6.1 where the credentials would be stripped out of the connection string before the __TransactionHistory table could be created in the circumstances given in the question (it also manifested in SQL Azure).

The bug has been fixed in the latest beta of EF (6.1.1-beta1).

Comment: Is it possible that this bug has been fixed for a particular Context mode only (object context precisely)

Because I've upgraded to Entity Framework 6.1.1 two projects, 1 in DbContext mode and 1 in Object Context mode (the two are Database First).

In the Object context mode project it works but in DbContext mode, I have the same problem as the one mentioned above.

My question is : Is the bug still there for the DbContext mode ?